# implementation of maximum matching algorithm

Tags: c#, nlp

I had a task to extract characters from a character stream, based on words in a
dictionary with relaxation of as it is occurrence of a word if not found in dictionary
so I successfully implemented it in C#, this works for longest matching

Thus all I had to do, was to sort dictionary based on length (descending order)

Now their are bonus marks for implementing the same task, to generate all possible
combinations so the term: thetabledownthere can be off two types:
the table down there
or
theta bled own there

Since I can traverse the sorted list bottom to top, to get minimal matching
but it would give me just two possibilities, their could be 3 or more for any
given chars

I was not able to find maximum matching algorithm or sample code in any prog. language
please share if you know some thing can be worked on !

Comment: i dont understand what you want??

Comment: I have a single character sequence e.g.: 'thetabledownthere' it can be segmented based on provided disctionary as two types:1) "the table down there" or 2) "theta bled own there" as the dictionary contains words: the, theta, table, there, own, etc ...

Comment: Yes and what is the problem?

Comment: problem is, based on longest matching algo, I was able to get longest i.e. "theta bled own there" but I want both, "the table down there" and "theta bled own there" 

the point is, I had to extract all possible words compared from a dictionary file [a text file having one word on each line], so some character input like the one 'thetabledownthere' can have 1, 2 or more possible extractions, I was able to get only longest matched words i.e. single extraction

Comment: Ah i understand now, what is the alghorithm that you use to find this?

Comment: And another thing lets say you have the string aaaaacataaaaa does it also have to match this but only uses the letters cat ofcourse. Or does the input string need to be constructed so that every letter corresponds to a word? So if we take your string **"thetabledownthere"** and in the dictionary there was the word **"thetabledownthe"** would the string match this word and leave **"re"** out?

Comment: I am really sorry as I dont seem to be able to xplain the thing, ok what you have asked, my program will generated only one extraction i.e. two words with a space: thetabledownthe re since thetabledownthe is already a complete entry in dictionary

Comment: for the input aaaaacataaaaa, it shall generate one extraction i.e. aaaaa cat aaaaa, since aaaaa is not in dictionary and cat is

Comment: Yes i understand now what you want, now i just need to know how you have the dictionary saved in your code is it a textfile or in a List<>?

Comment: thanks, I used a List<string> then I sorted it in decsending order